# File Content Not Present with Convertto-Json

Tags: rest, powershell, octopus-deploy

I am working on getting content from a site, put that content in a file, alter it and send it elsewhere all through Octopus. Right now I am stuck at "putting it in to a file". Locally, works great. This is what I have:

```
$GetBuildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -header $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Uri $Uri
$y = convertTo-json $GetBuildresponse -depth 99 | Out-file -FilePath "C:\test\File.json"
```

This works on my computer but fails in Octopus with the error:

> The converted JSON string is in bad format.

When I check the location that this file should be in, it's empty. Could anyone give me an idea as to what the cause might be?

EDIT:

My GET command ($GetBuildResponse above) returns this locally

```
*A bunch of text*
"variables": {
    "system.debug": {
        "value": "false",
        "allowOverride": true
    },
     "BuildVersion": {
        "value": "ValueIWantToChange"
    }
},
*A bunch of text*
```

In octopus I tried just getting the output from my GET statement and everything looks okay. The issue seems to be with the "ConvertTo-Json" command. When I convert, that's when I get the "bad format" error. I think the error is with the version of Powershell (4.0) although I probably won't be able to update PowerShell because that would require us to restart our machine.

Comment: I guess you data is truncated because it was still busy streaming at some point. Check with an online service like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ for what is wrong with your JSON file.

Comment: Can You post some example of $GetBuildResponse? 
It does read well from file on Your machine, right ? so maybe it's something about encoding when You write file? experiment with out-file -encoding maybe?

Comment: Yes, the json works perfect locally. I can use the get command, put response into a file, alter, and send back the response with a put command all fine. For whatever reason, I cant do this in Octopus.

Comment: Can you output the content of GetBuildresponse to a file to make sure there isn't some issue with your restmethod call..

Comment: That value of $GetBuildResponse you posted, is that the value when it fails during the octopus deployment? My best guess is that you are getting a HTML error page or Proxy/firewall error page on your request.

Answer (score 2):

It's possibly a problem with not being able to access the URL.

I just tried a deployment with a script step running on the Octopus server with script

```
$GetBuildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -header $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Uri http://localhost:8065/api
$y = convertTo-json $GetBuildresponse -depth 99 | Out-file -FilePath "./File.json"
New-OctopusArtifact -Path "./File.json" -Name "File.json"
```

It ran fine and returned the root API json as File.json.  So your script looks ok.

(I work for Octopus.  Feel free to reach out to us on support if you can't get it to work)